# Remove space after symbol

Tags: spacing, symbols

How can I remove the space after a symbol? The question comes from this example:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \begin{document}

            GD\& T

    \end{document}
```

will be typeset like:

`GD& T`

but I want:

`GD&T`

Comment: Welcome :) // Please provide complete code, using the Edit button, which we can copy and run. The answer often depends on your codes context. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried  `GD\&{}T` ?

Comment: Thank you! This works!

Comment: Glad to hear it … (I have also greatly reduced you MWE, as the other packages had nothing to do with the issue at hand.)

Comment: Spaces after control symbols such as `\&` are not ignored. Just type `GD\&T`

Comment: @Ingmar why `{}` ?

Comment: It's just an empty pair of brackets. Doesn't matter in this case, but sometimes a space or other delimiter is needed to distinguish between commands.